# Testing async component method

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a angular component and I want to test the state after calling a async method. How can I do this? My method doSomething not returns a promise!

```
angular.module('myModule').component('myComponent', {
  template: '<p></p>',
  controller: function($q) {
    this.state = 1;
    this.doSomething: function() {
      var that = this;
      setTimeout(function() { that.state = 2; }, 50);
    }
  }
});
```

**Test**

```
describe('Test', function() {
    var ctrl = null;

    beforeEach(module('myModule'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$componentController_) {
       ctrl = _$componentController_('myComponent', null, {});
    }));

    it('should be 2', function() {
      ctrl.doSomething();
      expect(ctrl.state).toBe(2);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wait for the update in the test, something like this:

```
describe('Test', function() {
    var ctrl = null;

    beforeEach(module('myModule'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$componentController_) {
       ctrl = _$componentController_('myComponent', null, {});
    }));

    it('should be 2', function(done) {
      ctrl.doSomething();
      setTimeout(function() { 
         expect(ctrl.state).toBe(2);
         done(); 
      }, 52);
    });
});
```

hope this help.